# Apply EQ to audio in and monitor audio out?

Tags: audio

This post was moved here from Stack overflow. I am trying to make it possible to take the microphone input, have the input be filtered by the ALSA EQ plugin (or any other controllable EQ), and hear the live filtered output through headphones. I am using a RPI on Raspbain Buster. How might I accomplish this?

Comment: `the microphone input` - what microphone?

Comment: I use a USB device for input